# DatePicker subclass can't find template

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker, custom-controls

Below is a piece of code from an attempt at subclassing the 4.0 DatePicker. One of the reasons I want to do this is to have more control over the Watermark. What happens here is that I get a handle to the DatePickerTextBox, but I am not getting the PART_Watermark (it is null).

Is ApplyTemplate the right place to do this? What must I fix to get the watermark?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
public class DatePickerEx : DatePicker
{

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var datePickerTextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as DatePickerTextBox;
        if (datePickerTextBox == null) return;

        var watermarkPart = datePickerTextBox.Template.FindName("PART_Watermark", datePickerTextBox) as ContentControl;
        if (watermarkPart == null) return;

        ...        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know too much about date picker but if `PART_TextBox` has its own template and `PART_Watermark` is part of that Template, you should call `ApplyTemplate` on the textbox before you can get access to its template parts.

Hope it helps.